# Unpacking C structure in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting a C-structure from C-client to python server over UDP socket. I am trying to read the message from it. I am having hard time figuring out the format for unpacking and also, printing the message. Can someone please help.

This is python server which receives the message form C client.

```
import socket
import sys
import struct

## struct Books {
##   char  title[50];
##   char  author[50];
##   char  subject[100];
##   int   book_id;
##};

##

UDP_IP = "localhost"
UDP_PORT = 12345

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    #print(f"received message:  {data}")
    print(f"received message:  {struct.unpack('50c50c100ci',data)}")
```

Following is c-client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     12345
#define MAXLINE 1024

// Driver code
struct Books {
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
};

int main() {
        int sockfd;
        char buffer[MAXLINE];
        char *hello = "Hello from client";
        struct sockaddr_in       servaddr;

        // Creating socket file descriptor
        if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
                perror("socket creation failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

        // Filling server information
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


        struct Books Book1;
        strcpy( Book1.title, "AAA");
        strcpy( Book1.author, "BBB");
        strcpy( Book1.subject, "CCC");
        Book1.book_id = 99999;

        int n, len;

        sendto(sockfd, &Book1, sizeof(Book1), MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        printf("Hello message sent.\n");

        n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, &len);
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        printf("Server : %s\n", buffer);

        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
}
```

Following is the output on server:

```
received message:  (b'A', b'A', b'A', b'\x00', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'5', b'\xbd', b'!', b'\xfc', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x03', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\xf0', b'4', b'\xbd', b'!', b'\xfc', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\xfc', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x10', b'U', b'B', b'B', b'B', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x03', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'P', b'\xf7', b'N', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\xe1', b'\x81', b'\xb2', b'N', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'_', b'\x9a', b'\x7f', b'g', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\xc8', b'\xd4', b'\xf8', b'N', b'C', b'C', b'C', b'\x00', b' ', b'6', b'\xbd', b'!', b'\xfc', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'X', b'Y', b'\xf7', b'N', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\xf0', b'\xc9', b'\xf8', b'N', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\xef', b'\xf1', b'\xd6', b'N', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x01', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'X', b'Y', b'\xf7', b'N', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x01', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x01', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\xf0', b'\xc9', b'\xf8', b'N', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\xc1', b'H', b'\xd6', b'N', b'z', b'\x7f', b'\x00', b'\x00', 99999)
```

Questions:

1. Is the format string used to unpack is correct ?
2. If unpack format is correct, why the print statement is still printing binary data ? How can I print it in readable format ?

Comment: Your C code is sending a bunch of junk data over the socket, since you only set a small fraction of `Book1`'s memory. That may be fine, but don't be surprised when what you receive on the Python end has a bunch of junk in it.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ,understood Thanks. . C-client is beyond my scope of my control. Is there any way I could get clean output from python end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unpack a `char[]` into a string, you need to use the `s` format specifier, not `c` (which will give you the individual `char` values as you have seen).

More specifically, `s` will give you a `bytes` object, which you can convert to a string with the `decode` method, optionally specifying the encoding being used.

The correct format string in your case would be `'50s50s100si'`.

Comment: Now I am getting AAA .BBB,CCC,99999  in the output. How to clean that out and pick(print) them individually ?

Comment: Is that not what you wanted? To "pick" individual items, use normal list indexing.

Comment: I am getting `b'BBB\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Pq\x13D\x7f\x00\x00\xe1\x81,\x13D\x7f\x00\x00_\x9a\x7fg\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc8\xd4r\x13'` when I do  list indexing for `[1]` I was hoping to only get `BBB`

Comment: It seems the problem you have asked about here is now solved and you now have a new problem. Please ask a new question.